# Remove specific directory from multiple users in Windows

Tags: cmd, rmdir, delete-directory

I'm trying to remove a specific directory from every User's AppData directory within Win7.  We had a bad install of Cisco on multiple computers, and part of fixing it is that we need to remove AppData\Local\Cisco from every user on the computer prior to uninstalling,  Wouldn't be an issue except every computer has anywhere from 5-20 users on it.  I've tried the following:

```
for /D %%f in (Cisco) do rmdir %%f /s
```

And running that from the Users directory.  It's not working though, and I'm unsure the best route to removing this directory from all users on the computer, if I try a del or rmdir with wildcards, that breaks as well.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this in the users folder from the cmd prompt and check that it returns the correct folders.

```
for /d /r %a in (cisc*) do @echo %a
```

If so then add the RD command.

```
for /d /r %a in (cisc*) do rd /q /s "%a"
```

Comment: It's not working, maybe it's because it's in AppData and that dir is hidden.  Is there any way to force it to look through hidden directories?

Comment: actually, nevermind, it was my error, this works perfectly.  thanks!